# How Do You Use A Database DataSet to Build a HighCharts Org Chart

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to create an org chart from my database. These are the fields that are returned in the dataset:

Product_ID
Parent_Product_ID
Product_Name
Product_Description
Manager_Name
Parent_Name
Level

When I look at the HighChart Org Chart Example I see the following attributes:

```
keys: ['from', 'to'],
            data: [
             ['Shareholders', 'Board'],
                ['Board', 'CEO'],
                ['CEO', 'CTO'],
            ['CEO', 'CPO'],
            ['CEO', 'CSO'],
                ['CEO', 'HR'],
                ['CTO', 'Product'],
                ['CTO', 'Web'],
                ['CSO', 'Sales'],
                ['HR', 'Market'],
                ['CSO', 'Market'],
                ['HR', 'Market'],
                ['CTO', 'Market']
        ],
         nodes: [{
            id: 'Shareholders'
        }, {
            id: 'Board'
        }, {
            id: 'CEO',
            title: 'CEO',
            name: 'Grethe Hjetland',
            image: 'https://wp-assets.highcharts.com/www-highcharts-com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/17131126/Highsoft_03862_.jpg'
        }, {
            id: 'HR',
            title: 'HR/CFO',
            name: 'Anne Jorunn Fjærestad',
            color: '#007ad0',
            image: 'https://wp-assets.highcharts.com/www-highcharts-com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/17131210/Highsoft_04045_.jpg'
        }, {
            id: 'CTO',
            title: 'CTO',
            name: 'Christer Vasseng',
            image: 'https://wp-assets.highcharts.com/www-highcharts-com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/17131120/Highsoft_04074_.jpg'
        }, {
            id: 'CPO',
            title: 'CPO',
            name: 'Torstein Hønsi',
            image: 'https://wp-assets.highcharts.com/www-highcharts-com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/17131213/Highsoft_03998_.jpg'
        }, {
            id: 'CSO',
            title: 'CSO',
            name: 'Anita Nesse',
            image: 'https://wp-assets.highcharts.com/www-highcharts-com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/17131156/Highsoft_03834_.jpg'
        }, {
            id: 'Product',
            name: 'Product developers'
        }, {
            id: 'Web',
            name: 'Web devs, sys admin'
        }, {
            id: 'Sales',
            name: 'Sales team'
        }, {
            id: 'Market',
            name: 'Marketing team',
            column: 5
        }],
```

The variable "this.data" contains the database query results.
The Product_ID and Parent_Product_ID are the keys that tie the rows together.
The data appears to be the unique Product_ID and Parent_Product_ID values.
The Node is the rest of the data.

How do I convert my dataset to populate these 3 attributes?

Comment: It would be possible to create a [mcve] with the data you want to render in this chart?

Comment: Please reproduce your issue on some online editor with the data sample that you want to implement.